# What did I do wrong Here 'ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.'? I use Access 2016

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2016

When I try to add "books" through my application, it will always say "System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.'" But I have established the OleDbConnection. What mistake did I do here?

```
Public Class clsBookDA
    Private Shared dcnBooks As New _
        OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\Temp\books.accdb")
    Private Shared books As New ArrayList()

    Private Shared aBook As clsBook
    Private Shared aBookdID, anAuthor, aTitle As String
    Private Shared aPurchasePrice, aSalePrice As Decimal
    Private Shared anInventory As Integer

    Public Shared Sub Initialize()
        dcnBooks.Open()
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub Terminate()
        dcnBooks.Close()
        dcnBooks.Dispose()
    End Sub
    Public Shared Function GetAll() As ArrayList
        Dim dapBooks As New OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim dtbBooks As New DataTable()
        Dim drwBook As DataRow

        dapBooks = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select*From Books", dcnBooks)
        dapBooks.Fill(dtbBooks)

        books.Clear()
        For Each drwBook In dtbBooks.Rows
            aBookdID = drwBook("BookID")
            anAuthor = drwBook("Author")
            aTitle = drwBook("Title")
            aPurchasePrice = drwBook("PurchasePrice")
            aSalePrice = drwBook("SalePrice")
            anInventory = drwBook("Inventory")
            Dim aBook As New clsBook(aBookdID, anAuthor, aTitle, aPurchasePrice, aSalePrice, anInventory)
            books.Add(aBook)
        Next
        Return books
    End Function
    Public Shared Sub Add(ByVal aBook As clsBook)
        Dim dapBooks As New OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO Books" & "VALUES('" &
            aBook.BookID & "','" & aBook.Author & "','" & aBook.Title & "','" &
            aBook.PurchasePrice & "','" & aBook.SalePrice & "','" &
            aBook.Inventory & "')"

        dapBooks.UpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, dcnBooks)
        dapBooks.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub Update(ByVal aBook As clsBook)
        Dim dapBooks As New OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE Books" & "SET Author = '" &
            aBook.Author & "', Title = '" & aBook.Title & "', PurchasePrice ='" &
            aBook.PurchasePrice & "', SalePrice= '" & aBook.SalePrice &
            "', Inventory= '" & aBook.Inventory & "'" &
            "WHERE BookID = '" & aBook.BookID & "'"

        dapBooks.UpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, dcnBooks)
        dapBooks.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Delete(ByVal aBook As clsBook)
        Dim dapBooks As New OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Books WHERE BookID='" &
            aBook.BookID & "'"

        dapBooks.UpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, dcnBooks)
        dapBooks.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the Initialize method that opens the connection to the db?  Also, would look at implementing you're connection handling with a Using clause to prevent issues as a result of connections being left open

Comment: ArrayList ??? How old is you text book? ArrayList should not be used in new code. Check out Lis(Of T)

Answer (score 2):

As to `ArrayList` see the Remarks section at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0

Database objects like connections and commands need to be closed and disposed as soon as possible. It is better to keep them in the method where they are used. Using blocks insure that these objects are cleaned up even if there is an error.

Always use parameters to avoid Sql injection. In Access the order that parameters appear in the sql statement must be the same as the order that the parameters are added to the parameters collection.

`DataAdapter`s have extra functionality that you are not using in your code. Use the lighter weight command object.

I see you appear to be putting single quotes around your numeric types in your concatenated sql strings. If these are really numbers in Access this will cause a problem. Parameters avoid this problem by providing the database type so no single quotes are required in the in the sql string.

Don't pass the entire `clsBook` to the delete sub. Just pass the id.

I will leave it to you to rewrite the Update code.

```
Public Class clsBookDA
    Private Shared ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\Temp\books.accdb"

    Public Shared Function GetAll() As List(Of clsBook)
        Dim dtbBooks As New DataTable()
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * From Books", cn)
            cn.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dtbBooks.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Dim lst As New List(Of clsBook)
        For Each drwBook As DataRow In dtbBooks.Rows
            Dim bk As New clsBook(drwBook("BookID").ToString, drwBook("Author").ToString, drwBook("Title").ToString, CDec(drwBook("PurchasePrice")), CDec(drwBook("SalePrice")), CInt(drwBook("Inventory")))
            lst.Add(bk)
        Next
        Return lst
    End Function
    Public Shared Sub Add(ByVal aBook As clsBook)
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO Books VALUES(@ID, @Author, @Title, @PurchasePrice, @SalePrice, @Inventory);"
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, cn)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = aBook.BookID
                .Add("@Author", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = aBook.Author
                .Add("@Title", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = aBook.Title
                .Add("@PurchasePrice", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = aBook.PurchasePrice
                .Add("@SalePrice", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = aBook.SalePrice
                .Add("@Inventory", OleDbType.Integer).Value = aBook.Inventory
            End With
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub Update(ByVal aBook As clsBook)
        'To do
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Delete(BookID As String)
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Books WHERE BookID=@BookID;"
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = BookID
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class clsBook
    Public Property BookID As String
    Public Property Author As String
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property PurchasePrice As Decimal
    Public Property SalePrice As Decimal
    Public Property Inventory As Integer

    Public Sub New(id As String, auth As String, titl As String, purch As Decimal, sale As Decimal, inv As Integer)
        BookID = id
        Author = auth
        Title = titl
        PurchasePrice = purch
        SalePrice = sale
        Inventory = inv
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @BartHofland When the command is disposed it takes care of its connection property and disposes that also.

Comment: @BartHofland Thank you for the information. I got this from someone far more experienced than I. I took the explanation, which I didn't fully understand, on faith. I will be going back to my old pattern of wrapping the connection explicitly with a using.

Comment: @BartHofland I wonder what I edited because it wasn't this answer. Oh well. It is 4Am here. Time for some sleep.